# Shutting down Custom Thread Pool executor in grpc Spring boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, grpc-java

I am creating an application where I am using Spring Boot to build a gRPC client and server.
I have a requirement where I want to shutdown my service after 9 hours. It's started again next day.
For grpc Server, a deafult thread pool is provided, but we can provide our own custom thread pool by calling, `serverBuilder.executor(our custom executor)`
But when we provide our custom executor it becomes our responsibility to shut it down.

Now, if we don't use Spring Boot, we can call shutDown()/shutDownNow() inside our custom method which we use to terminate our service.

But when we use Spring Boot, we provide custom executor like this

```
@Component
public class BootGrpcConfiguration extends GRpcServerBuilderConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void configure(ServerBuilder<?> serverBuilder) {
        ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        serverBuilder.executor(threadPoolExecutor);

    }

}
```

Now to shut it down there are multiple possible ways:

1. use awaitTermination(9, TimeUnit.HOURS) inside the configure method itself
2. Make my cutom execuotr a bean and shut it down from anywhere in the code
3. Declare ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor instance out of method and use some kind of getter to get it and then call shutdDown methods on it from anywhere in the code.

Which way do you think would be more efficient?
In particular I want to ask whether making the custom executor a bean would be a good idea?

Comment: i think custom executor will be good... here u configure corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, queueSize, priority queue, etc.. you have more controll here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell spring what to do when your component is destroyed, for example:

```
@Component
public class BootGrpcConfiguration extends GRpcServerBuilderConfigurer{

    private ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void configure(ServerBuilder<?> serverBuilder) {
        serverBuilder.executor(threadPoolExecutor);

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

If you create the thread pool as a bean, then you can declare the destroy method there:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ExecutorService initializeExecutorService() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }
}
```

You will need of course a custom executor that doesn't accepts new jobs during some period of time:

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor() {

    @Override   
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        // do some checks here
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, as I am new to Spring and Spring Boot, I didn't know about the @PreDestroy annotation. That's really efficient.